# Running a loop again and passing the control to Main class in Java after output

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I am trying to make a simple JAVA program that will help a user select a car of his choice.

```
public class CarSelector {
static CarSelector start = new CarSelector();

public String BodyType(String a){
    String hatchBack, SUV, MUV, compactSedan, sedan, saloon, miniVan, convertible, hybrid, coupe;

    if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("a")){
        hatchBack = "polo";
        System.out.println("We recommend: " +hatchBack);
    }
    String b = "";
    if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("b")){
        SUV = "Fortuner";
        System.out.println("We recommend: " +SUV);
    }

    if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("c")){
        compactSedan = "Amaze";
        System.out.println("We recommend: " +compactSedan);
    }

    if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("d")){
        sedan = "Vento";
        System.out.println("We recommend: " +sedan);
    }

    if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("e")){
        saloon = "Corolla";
        System.out.println("We recommend: " +saloon);
    }

    if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("f")){
        MUV = "Innova";
        System.out.println("We recommend: " +MUV);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Incorrect choice.");
        System.out.println(a);
        //start.BodyType(a);
        return null;
    }
    System.out.println("We recommend: " +a);

    return null ;
}

public int PriceRange(){
    int price5 = 5;
    int price10 = 10;
    int price15 = 15;
    int price20 = 20;
    int price25 = 25;
    int price30 = 30;


    return 0 ;
}

public String SegmentBest(){
    //string type of the best cars within price range
    return null;
}

public int OnRoadPrice(){
    //return int of on road price
    return 0;
}

public String Manufacturer(){
    //all manufacturers with their models available
    String Toyota, Volkswagen, Honda;
    String i1= "Toyota";
    String i2= "Volkswagen";
    String i3= "Honda";
    return null;
}

public int SeatingCapacity(){
    //return integer seating capacity

    return 0;
}

public String ReviewLink(){
    return null;
}

public String LatestReleases(){
    return null;

}

public String FuelType(){
    return null;

}

public static void main (String[] args){


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String option;

    System.out.println("Welcome to car selector: ");
    System.out.println("Choose according to: ");
    System.out.println("A:Body Type");
    System.out.println("B: Manufacturer");
    System.out.println("C: Price Range");
    option = input.nextLine();

    if( option.equalsIgnoreCase("a")){
        System.out.println("A: Hatchback");
        System.out.println("B: SUV");
        System.out.println("C: MUV");
        System.out.println("D: Sedan");
        System.out.println("E: Saloon");
        System.out.println("F: Compact Sedan");
        String optionA = input.nextLine();
        start.BodyType(optionA);
    }



}
```

}

The code is simple. A walkthrough: The main class will prompt the user to make a choice of how he wants to choose a car. Given option "A" as a choice will run the first method. Here are my queries

- Within the BodyType method, I would like to run the set of IF statements again if the user enters anything other than a,b,c,d,e,f
- How can I hand the control back to the main class (run a specific code from MAIN method) and also start a method from another method (from BodyType to PriceRange). I hope I was clear. Thanks, Cheers!

Comment: i think you are not clear to me :), how would you want you price range associate to your body type (or i might wrong here), where is the relation here. you have simple method with price tag?!!!

Comment: Got the answer to my second query over here. Calling method within another method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325779/calling-a-method-inside-another-method-in-same-class

Answer (score 0):

you can play it now...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CarSelector {
    static CarSelector start = new CarSelector();

    static String[] bodytypes = new String[]{"hatchBack", "SUV", "MUV", "compactSedan", "sedan",
            "saloon", "miniVan", "convertible", "hybrid", "coupe"};
    static String[] manufacturers = new String[]{"Toyota", "Volkswagen", "Honda"};

    private String getBodyType(int bt) {
        if(bt >= bodytypes.length){
            System.err.println("Incorrect choice.");
            return null;
        }else{
            System.out.println("We recommend: " + bodytypes[bt]);
            return bodytypes[bt];
        }
    }

    public static String getManufacturer(int mf) {
        if(mf >= manufacturers.length){
            System.err.println("Incorrect choice.");
            return null;
        }else{
            System.out.println("We recommend: " + manufacturers[mf]);
            return manufacturers[mf];
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String bodyType = "";
        String manufacturer = "";

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String option;

        System.out.println("Welcome to car selector: ");
        System.out.println("Choose according to: ");
        pringSelectType();
        option = input.nextLine();

        while(!option.equalsIgnoreCase("o")){
            if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
                for(int a = 0; a < bodytypes.length ; a++){
                    System.out.println(a+": "+ bodytypes[a]);
                }
                option = input.nextLine();
                bodyType = start.getBodyType(Integer.parseInt(option));
                pringSelectType();
                option = input.nextLine();
            }else if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
                for(int a = 0; a < manufacturers.length ; a++){
                    System.out.println(a+": "+ manufacturers[a]);
                }
                option = input.nextLine();
                manufacturer = getManufacturer(Integer.parseInt(option));
                pringSelectType();
                option = input.nextLine();
            }else{
                option = input.nextLine();
                System.err.println(("input a right choice"));
                pringSelectType();
                option = input.nextLine();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("it's your choice below: ");
        System.out.println("bodyType : "+ bodyType);
        System.out.println("manufacturer : "+ manufacturer);

    }

    private static void pringSelectType() {
        System.out.println("A:Body Type");
        System.out.println("B: Manufacturer");
        System.out.println("C: Price Range");
    }
}
```

i delete some unused method,and change some code.
i don't make any note,cause i think it's easy enough..

if u have some problem,comment it,i will see.

PS:when u want to over the select system,input o.it will be done.