# Understanding method in Activity

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
}
```

This is a beginner question but i cant seem to understand it ,also I searched and couldn't find the same question.

Here is what i understand:

Class `MainActivity` is extending `AppCompatActivity` thus it can use the fields and methods of the parent class.

The `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {` is a method inside the parent class and its getting overridden.Then the `super` keyword is used to call the `onCreate(..)` method.

Now What i dont understand is the `setContentView(..)` method. I thought that in java we should use an `obj.method` or `super.method` or `ClassName.method`(if static) to call a method. But here the method is used alone. I just need a small explanation or a redirection to the right place.

Thank you.

Comment: the setContentView is also a method from AppCompatActivity or any of its parents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SetContentView is a method which we inherits when we extends an Activity class which
Set the activity content from a layout resource. The resource will be inflated, adding all top-level views to the activity. Activity uses setContentView(R.layout.main) to set xml layout to that activity which will actually render as the UI of your activity.

Comment: Yes I understand that , but how are we able to call it without using the `super` keyword?

Comment: because you can call method of parent class without any super refrence

Comment: the super is mandatory when you want to call the method from the parent, in your case, since you override the onCreate you must call super.onCreate in order to call the parent method, since you did not override the setContentView you do not need the keyword

Comment: If you try to override a function which already exists in parent activity than you use super.functionname to tell java that 1st do everything happening in parent function and than do things which i wrote now if you dont call super when you override than parent logic will not be called... But here you are not overriding a function you are just calling it so you dont need to use super

Comment: So since I overriden the onCreate then I add super.onCreate, so the compiler knows that i need both what i wrote in the overriden onCreate and what is written in the parent class. I understand it now thank you. I thought we had to use `super` keyword always to access from parent.

Answer (score 1):

In such case java implicitly assumes a reference to the current object.

```
setContentView(...)
```

is same as

```
this.setContentView(...)
```

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7325813/1847333) to similar question

Answer (score 0):

This is from [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

> onCreate(Bundle) is where you initialize your activity. Most importantly, here you will usually call setContentView(int) with a layout resource defining your UI, and using findViewById(int) to retrieve the widgets in that UI that you need to interact with programmatically.

This is to set the main view of your activity 
Look at the link there is a lot of explanation in it.

Comment: Original question is more about java syntax and scope. You arent' answering it.

Answer (score 0):

For easy understand let me give you one example

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

//Two methods in super class
    public void showProgress() {
        //your code
    }

    public void hideProgress() {

     //your code
    }

}
```

This is BaseActivity which is super class for other activity

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Direct access to BaseClass Method
        showProgress();
    }

}
```

As you can see you can directly access BaseClass method

if still any confusion let me know...

Answer (score 0):

Please check the above example;
methodX is a replica of the `setContentView()` method in your code.
They are both methods of the sub classes. Thus no need for declaring with super keyword

```
public class Base {

    public void method_pub(){
        System.out.println("Method is public");

    }
    protected void method_pro(){`enter code here
        System.out.println("Method is protected");
    }
}

public class Que1 extends Base {

    public void methodX(){}

    @Override
    protected void method_pro() {

        super.method_pro();
        methodX();
    }
}
```