# I can't figure out how to get the third method to print out in the fourth method

Tags: java, methods, boolean

The Third Method is supposed to figure out if the year is a leap year or not and the fourth is supposed to print the info out through a string? But I don't know how? **AFTER EDIT*** Still giving me an errors. Don't know why

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeapYear {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    displayInstructions();
    int year = getYear();
    isLeap(year);
}

public static void displayInstructions() {
    System.out.println("This program asks you to enter a year as a 4 digit number. The output will indicate whether the year you entered is a leap year.");
}

public static int getYear() {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a year: ");
    int year = reader.nextInt();
    return year;
}

public static boolean isLeap(boolean year) {
    if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100) {
        isleap = true;

    }
    else {
        return false;
    }



}
public static void displayResuls(isLeap year) {
  if (isLeap)
  {
    System.out.println("Year" +year+" is a Leap Year.");
  }

  else {
  System.out.println("Year" +year+ "is not a Leap Year"");

   }

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a method inside another method in same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325779/calling-a-method-inside-another-method-in-same-class)

Answer (score 0):

In the same way you store the result from getYear() into a variable and pass that value as a parameter to isLeap you need to do the same with the result from isLeap and pass that value as a parameter to displayResults